# How do I write the data of an object to a file and then parse it back into a new object when the file is read

Tags: java, parsing, string-formatting

I'm trying to write a chat bot for twitch and I was looking to store a list of all of the viewers who have ever visited the channel as well as some data that I store for each individual user. These include thing like their username, level, how many points they have, etc. So far what I have is to use `String.format()` to create a string for a file that will then we written to a file with a `bufferedWritter`. I would like to be able to get the list of viewers out every time I restart the bot after things like maintenance or adding new features. I'm just not sure if I'm doing this the most efficient way and I have no clue how to read it without running a for loop that checks for the position of semicolons and fills in the data with substrings.

```
public abstract class Viewer {
    private String username;
    private int level;
    private int exp;
    private int points;
    private int intermediatePoints;
    private boolean isMod;
    private boolean isPreviousWinner;
    private boolean enteredRaffle;

    public Viewer(String username){
        this.username = username;
        this.level = 0;
        this.exp = 0;
        this.points = 0;
        this.intermediatePoints = 0;
        this.isMod = false;
        this.isPreviousWinner = false;
        this.enteredRaffle = false;
    }

    public Viewer(String username, int level, int exp, int points, int intermediatePoints, 
            boolean isMod, boolean isPreviousWinner, boolean enteredRaffle){
        this.username = username;
        this.level = level;
        this.exp = exp;
        this.points = points;
        this.intermediatePoints = intermediatePoints;
        this.isMod = isMod;
        this.isPreviousWinner = isPreviousWinner;
        this.enteredRaffle = enteredRaffle;
    }

public String setViewerString(){
        String viewerDataString = String.format("%s;%d;%d;%d;%d;%b;%b;%b;", 
                username, level, exp, points, intermediatePoints, isMod, isPreviousWinner, enteredRaffle);
        return viewerDataString;
    }

    public void parseViewerDataString(){

    }
}
```

Sorry if I was too specific, I've never asked a question here before and I wasn't sure how much info was too much.

Comment: Please 'tag' the language

Comment: Gson seems useful here. Can read and write objects to JSON in maybe like 4 lines of code

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should make a class serializable by implementing 
serializable interface avilable in "java.io.Serializable" package

object of such class can be Serialize(saved in a file) and de-serialize
have a look at [serialization](http://www.javatpoint.com/serialization-in-java) in java

Answer (score 0):

Use java.io.PrintWriter and java.io.BufferedReader classes for write/read to files. Documentation found here:

[BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html)

[PrintWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html)

As for parsing the data after reading from the file, you might try something like this:

```
public void parseViewerDataString(String dataString){
    String[] dataArray = dataString.split(";");
    //This will automatically split up the string in between semicolons

    //Then use dataArray to assign values to field

    username = dataArray[0];
    level = Integer.parseInt(dataArray[1]);
    exp = Integer.parseInt(dataArray[2]);
    //And so on...
}
```